# How does Spark in Java compare two Keys when doing a join or groupWith?

Tags: java, join, apache-spark

I am trying to do the following,

```
JavaPairRDD<JsonObject, JsonObject> rdd1 = ..
JavaPairRDD<JsonObject, String> rdd2 = .. 
JavaPairRDD<JsonObject, Tuple2<Iterable<String>, Iterable<JsonObject>>> 
groupedRDD = rdd1.groupWith(rdd2);
```

But I'm not sure how Spark will compare two JsonObject keys.

More generally, how are keys compared when doing a join or groupWith?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the Java `.equals()` method.

The thing is `equals()` is not implemented in `JsonObject`. So it will use the default Java implementation which compares just object references.

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Comment: I'm using com.google.gson.JsonObject as my JsonObject class, which does implement equals.  So I believe my code should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately com.google.gson.JsonObject is not serializable, so it only works if the data is not transmitted across the network.  I have worked around this and no longer use JSON as a key.  It is fraught with issues, and I don't suggest it.